# distances between communities/cultures in fantasy world, approximate to 12th - 13th century

Tags: internal-consistency, fantasy-races

So - in my book, I have a healthy young 20-something character travel for 5 days between his woodland home and the nearest big city, by foot.

It is set in a fantasy world approximate to Britain around 12th-13th century.

Do you think that is far enough away for the cultures to be very different? (same race but different religious beliefs - for example).

And is it far away enough for the tiny kingdom of the city to effectively ignore the woodlands villagers - and not be at war/trade with them?

I envision the woodland village to be very secluded away from the world as its deep in the woods.

Comment: You can have very different cultures on the two banks of a river... For example, up the second half of the 19th century, on the left bank of the lower Danube was Wallachia (Christian, spoke Romanian) and on the right bank was Turkey (Muslim, spoke Turkish).

Comment: In that era, there was only one "big city" in Europe, Constantinople, and it had a population much smaller than Des Moines, Iowa today.  The other "cities" we would today call "towns" of perhaps a few tens of thousands.

Comment: thanks - in the book i've actually used the word town, with population of around 15-20,000... a rapidly growing place soon to be considered a major city... but not quite yet :)
How does that sound?

Comment: @user535733: With a population of about 100,000, there was also Palermo as the second biggest European city in the 12th century when it was the capital of the kingdom of Sicily. It saw a massive decline in population in the late 13th century. Wikipedia has an interesting page on [historical urban community sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_urban_community_sizes) for an overview.

Answer (score 5):

Typically there are small villages about every 1 hour (3 to 4 miles of travel). Assuming travel by road and on foot, your adventurer would cover 3.5 mph x 8 hours per day of travel x 5 days = 180 miles of distance. That's roughly the width of the Florida or parts of the Yucatan peninsula. It is possible, even in the modern world for cultures to be different across that distance. Depending on where political borders are, it's possible to be in a different nation with different customs. Depending on how inaccessible the territory is (marsh, high mountains, desert between them) the two societies may even have limited contact with one another and the new culture be very alien.

Medieval kingdoms were hands-off. A Baron looked after his town, a Count his county, and a Duke his province. Top concerns was that taxes (in terms of custom) were collected in the amount expected by your superiors and delivered on time. With the exception of nobles driving personal social causes (sometimes disparaging called novelties in histories), as long as the taxes were paid and trouble wasn't being caused, areas were ignored.

Comment: my test reader said 5 days felt too close - but i calculated about 20 miles a day  = 100 miles - so i guess thats just fine then :)
thank you Sir :)

Answer (score 4):

The average walking speed of a human is 3.1 mph, and from some cursory Google searches, the average human can walk 20-30 miles in one day. Eight hours' walking at 3.1 mph gives us a distance of 24.8 miles, slap bang in the middle of that estimate; multiply that by five for a final distance of 124 miles (~200km). That's roughly the distance between Vienna, Austria and Budapest, Hungary.

Honestly, however, I would expect a woodland village to have a "very different culture" from a big city, regardless of proximity, just because that's what I've come to expect as a fantasy reader. If everyone in the city acted exactly the same as the people in the village, I'd see it as lazy world-building and/or lazy writing. So this is one of those things that, to me, doesn't need justifying; you can just *do it*, and most readers will accept it without thinking twice about it.

As for the people of the city ignoring the villagers, that seems perfectly plausible too. It's too small and too far away to be any kind of threat, so there's no point going to war with it, and if the village has nothing they want, then there's no point trading with it either, especially if it's difficult to get to due to its position deep in the woods.

Comment: great - this fits with my thoughts - thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

**As different as you want.**

Consider islam-occupied Spain. When the "moros" conquered parts of the peninsula, it remained under their control for hundreds of years. At the time, in a couple of days you could go from a spanish kingdom to a islamic city (not sure if you could arrive with your head over your shoulders, but you could in theory).

Answer (score 0):

5 days on foot? Nearest city? Is the Britain the size of America?  Just a note that in your fantasy world you need to remove some things to make it fantasy. 5 days was what it took, on foot, to go from London to Hadrians Wall. Roman roads baby.
You need to have very bad infrastructure to be 5 day travel from "nearest" city. I mean very very bad. Like two mountains range and a 50 kilometer swamp in beetwen. And you only go uphill. In snow. In the night. Fighting off wolves.

A modern, non-seasoned walker, could go 25-30 kilometres per day (and by modern I mean a person who mostly sit and have very little to no activity). So it would take them 3 days to go from London to Dover.

If you go by 5 days then not only the City ignore the woodland people. They might not even know they exist. They might be in totally different kingdom.

How different they might be? You had Constantinopole siege in 1204. In one day you could go from Scotland to England. Or take a ferry to Ireland.